# How to get my deleted columns back in an Excel file, that were exported from SharePoint lists

Tags: excel, export

I have a list in Sharepoint, and I export it to Excel. All fields get exported, so evetything is fine. Then I deside that I for example no longer want the "Modified by" field in the excel file, and I remove it from the Excel file. So next time I do the Refresh, I get all the field, but not the "Modified by". So, just as I wanted. I now have the "Modified by" in my view, but not in my Excel.

Then I change my mind: Now I want my "Modified by" back in my Excel file!
I have lots of formatting and macros in my Excel, so I do not want do a new export.
How can I do this ***without*** removing and re-adding the "Modified by" field in the Sharepoint view?

Comment: I have this same question... the Excel columns stay in sync with the columns on the SharePoint view until you deleted it from the Excel sheet... then it is as if it is "marked" and will not return. Anybody know if the column can be linked up with the Excel sheet again without redoing the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

After much poking around, I figured out how to do this.

If you clear the check from box in the setting found in Data > Proprieties > Preserve column/sort/filter layout (uncheck this), when you refresh your data with the SP list, this previously deleted SP column (the one deleted in Excel) will come back (assuming it is included in the SP view that the connection is linked to). When you refresh the data with this box unchecked, any other columns you may have added will disappear, such as columns inserted to calculated things, etc. Also, custom formatting you applied will be lost.

I hope this helps someone else who finds them self in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things, an easy trick fixed this issue for me. After adding the column again to the View in SharePoint, I just renamed it in SP and then refreshed the data in the Excel file. That got it back! Hope it helps you!